# Postfix header_checks not working: Invalid preceding regular expression

Tags: postfix, regular-expressions

I have a problem with Postfix.
Recently we are receiving mail messages with malformed "From:" headers as these:

```
From: "Name Surname <user@good-domain.com>" <user2@bad-domain.com>
From: "user@good-domain.com" <user2@bad-domain.com>
```

Ended up with a solution based on PCRE header checks, with these two regexp:

```
/^From:.+(".+<(.*@+.*)>").*<((?!\2).*)>$/ REJECT
/^From:.+("([^<>]*@+[^<>]*)").*<((?!\2).*)>$/ REJECT
```

Done

```
postmap /etc/postfix/header_checks
```

and reloaded postfix.

Seems to work ok and POstfix apparently handles the PCRE with no problem:

```
postmap -q 'From: "Name Surname <user@good-domain.com>" <user2@bad-domain.com>' pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
REJECT
postmap -q 'From: "user@good-domain.com" <user2@bad-domain.com>' pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
REJECT
```

But in real usage the mails are not blocked. In the log there are the following (repeated) errors:

```
Nov 22 10:52:19 mx1 postfix/cleanup[32087]: warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/header_checks, line 497: Invalid preceding regular expression
Nov 22 10:52:19 mx1 postfix/cleanup[32087]: warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/header_checks, line 498: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

The content of the /etc/postfix/header_checks file is the following (the first 496 lines are comments):

```
/^From:.+(".+<(.*@+.*)>").*<((?!\2).*)>$/ REJECT
/^From:.+("([^<>]*@+[^<>]*)").*<((?!\2).*)>$/ REJECT
/^Subject:/ WARN
```

Additional info:

```
- There are no receive_override_options: the file is used as the subject are correctly logged in logfile (last line). And the errors too shows the file is handled by postfix.
- Tested the two regexp with multiple online services and they seems correct: also the postmap -q tests shows they are working correctly.
- Postfix 2.10.1 and PCRE 8.32 on a CentOS 7.7
```

Any idea?